# Static int pointer arithmetics causes valgrind invalid read

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, queue, valgrind

I'm trying to create queue as double void pointer.`pollQueue` function is used to process queue and return queue element pointer `dest`.

I have managed to simplify problem into this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void **queue;
int queueSize = 0;

int pollQueue(void **dest, int *processPlace);
int processQueue();


int main(void){

    int data = 5;
    
    queue = malloc(sizeof(void *));
    queueSize++;
    *queue = &data;
    
    processQueue();
    
    free(queue);
    
    return 0;
}

int processQueue(){

    void *queueElement = NULL;
    int processPlace = -1;


    while(pollQueue(&queueElement, &processPlace) == 0)
    {        
        //do something with queue element
    };

    return 0;
}

int pollQueue(void **dest, int *processPlace){

    static int processNumber = 0;

    //void *cur = queue[processNumber];
    void *cur = *(queue + processNumber); //0 here

    printf("process number: %i\n", processNumber);

    //if end of the queue reached retun 0 and prepare for next poll
    if(!cur || queueSize == processNumber)
    {
        *processPlace = processNumber;
        dest = NULL;
        processNumber = 0;
        return 1;
    }

    *processPlace = processNumber;
    *dest = cur;

    processNumber++;

    return 0;
}
```

When I run this code through valgrind i get this:

```
==14570== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==14570== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==14570== Using Valgrind-3.18.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==14570== Command: ./test
==14570== 
process number: 0
==14570== Invalid read of size 8
==14570==    at 0x1092B4: pollQueue (in /home/jan/Documents/programing/c_c++/population/sim/test/test)
==14570==    by 0x10926A: processQueue (in /home/jan/Documents/programing/c_c++/population/sim/test/test)
==14570==    by 0x109202: main (in /home/jan/Documents/programing/c_c++/population/sim/test/test)
==14570==  Address 0x4a96048 is 0 bytes after a block of size 8 alloc'd
==14570==    at 0x4848899: malloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==14570==    by 0x1091D4: main (in /home/jan/Documents/programing/c_c++/population/sim/test/test)
==14570== 
process number: 1
==14570== 
==14570== HEAP SUMMARY:
==14570==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==14570==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 2 frees, 1,032 bytes allocated
==14570== 
==14570== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==14570== 
==14570== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==14570== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

I don't understand what is causing error and I find it even more strange, when I put 0 explicitly to simulate what should happen during first call of function. Error disappear.

```
int pollQueue(void **dest, int *processPlace){

    static int processNumber = 0;

    //void *cur = queue[processNumber];
    void *cur = *(queue + 0); //0 here

    printf("process number: %i\n", processNumber);

    //if end of the queue reached retun 0 and prepare for next poll
    if(!cur || queueSize == processNumber)
    {
        *processPlace = processNumber;
        dest = NULL;
        processNumber = 0;
        return 1;
    }

    *processPlace = processNumber;
    *dest = cur;

    processNumber++;

    return 0;
}
```

I can't explain why using variable should this cause invalid read but when value is given implicitly it works fine. Can someone explain this?

Comment: Please avoid writing code like `*(queue + processNumber)`. `queue[processNumber]` is easier to understand.

Comment: What's the point of `dest = NULL;`? Did you mean `*dest = NULL;`?

Comment: `static int processNumber = 0;` is only initialised *once* not on subsequent calls. That's why there is a difference when you by-pass it.

Comment: You need to check if `processNumber` is less than `queueSize` before doing `void *cur = *(queue + processNumber);`

Comment: @WeatherVane Isn't that the point? It increments it at the end of the function so the next call will get the next item.

Comment: @Barmar OP is comparing `*(queue + processNumber);` with `*(queue + 0);`. They are not the same. `queue = malloc(sizeof(void *));` only allocates one element.

Comment: Well, duh! The problem is that when you increment `processNumber` it goes out of range of the allocation. You need to use `realloc()` to grow the queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole point of `static` function variables is that they keep their value between calls.

The first time you call `processQueue`, `processNumber` starts as `0`. Before the function exits, `processNumber` is incremented to `1`.

The second time you call `processQueue`, `processNumber` starts as `1`. Since `queue` only has one element, accessing `*(queue + processNumber)` aka `queue[processNumber]` results in undefined behaviour.

`valgrind` is catching this serious error.